# Google Maps not displaying user current position

Tags: java, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-markers

I am trying to display a user's current position on my android application. I've tried testing the application on an Android 6.0 phone. However, upon clicking the button on the top right corner of the Google Maps activity, nothing happens on the screen. Below is my MapsActivity java code.

```java
package com.example.nibebe;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

import static com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.*;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;


        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        // LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        // mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient()
    {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        mLastLocation = location;

        LatLng latLng= new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

    }



    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_LOW_POWER);
        // LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder= new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);

        // LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

    }
}
```

Below is my AndroidManifest.xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.nibebe">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_car"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
        -->
        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"></activity>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
    </application>


</manifest>
```

I expect upon tapping on that button, the map moves and displays a marker.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You add a marker using the below example code

This code is explained here [Google developer Documentation - Adding a Map with a marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map-with-marker)

--EDIT--

To get the current location AKA last known location, using this documentation [Get the last known location](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current#java)

```
fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
  .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(Location location) {
          // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
          if (location != null) {
              //pass the two parameter
              LatLng sydney = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
              googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney)
              .title("Marker in My current location"));
              googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
          }
      }
  });
```

Comment: I would like the marker to display my current position.

Answer (score 0):

it's better to use [FusedLocationProviderApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi)

Location currentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);